# I want to delete an entry in a cookie based table with a button

Tags: php, cookies

Hello I am struggling to delete a row in this table but with button 
not like this.
Please if there is a way share it
I would be very grateful.
If there is a javascript or php way please share it because i am realy stuck.

```
    if( isset( $_COOKIE[ 'contacts'] ) ){
        $contacts= unserialize( $_COOKIE['contacts']);
    }

    if( isset( $_POST[ 'f_name'] ) ){
        /*
        *   If at least one character in all array
        */
        if( implode( "", $_POST) != "" ) {


                if( !in_array ( $_POST, $contacts) ) {

                    $contacts[]= $_POST;
                }
                else {
                    $error = "Not uniq!";
                }
        }
        else {
            $error="Please, insert a contact!";
        }           
    } 

        /**
        *   Save in cookie contact when No error
        **/

        setcookie('contacts', serialize($contacts), time()+ 60*60*24*365);

        /**
        * delete cookie contacts when click delete button
        **/
        setcookie('contacts', serialize($contacts), time()- 60*60*24*365);
```

?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is the differentiation for handling the click of a delete button?  The above doesn't seem to handle anything of that sort and will always save the cookie with a proper time and then it will delete the cookie (by setting the negative time).  It's rather redundant.

There needs to be a call to action (the button) and a corresponding event handler.  The PHP you provided doesn't seem to handle a delete scenario and the last two cookie settings cancel each other out.

You could handle this a couple of different ways - javascript/jQuery and PHP.

With PHP, you can simply set up a form to send a value through like this...

```
<form method="post" action="enterpagehere">
    <input type="submit" name="delete_btn" value="Delete Cookie">
</form>
```

Followed by this with PHP on whatever enterpagehere is to handle it.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["delete_btn"]) {
        setcookie('contacts', '', time()- 60*60*24*365);
    }
?>
```

You could alternately do it all on one page with some jQuery, using the same HTML above and the following...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('input[name="delete_btn"]').on('click',function(e) {
            document.cookie = 'contacts=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```